# google.maps.Data layer zIndex change is not reflecting on map

Tags: google-maps, gis, sequence, z-index, google-datalayer

I am trying to add **2** **google.maps.Data** layers one has all the google.maps.Data.Feature of type *Point* and another is **google.maps.Data.Feature** of type *Polygon*. I want to see the polygon data layer in the front and point data layer at the back.So i am setting **zIndex** for polygon data layer like this.

```
styleFunction1 : function(feature, resolution){
    var styleOption = {
                      fillColor:"#AAAAAA",
                      fillOpacity:1,
                      strokeColor:"#000000",
                      strokeOpacity:1,
                      strokeWeight:1,
                      zIndex:4000000000
                      };
    return styleOption;
},
datalayer1.setStyle(this.styleFunction1.bind(this));
```

And for Point data layer like this

```
styleFunction2 : function(feature, resolution){
        var styleOption = {icon :{
                                 fillColor:"#FF0000",
                                 fillOpacity:1,
                                 path:"M -1,-1  L -1,1  L 1,1  L 1,-1  L -1,-1  
                                       Z",
                                 rotation:0,
                                 scale:"6",
                                 strokeColor:"#000000",
                                 strokeOpacity:1,
                                 strokeWeight:1
                          },
                          zIndex:2000000001
                         };
        return styleOption;
    },
datalayer2.setStyle(this.styleFunction2.bind(this));
```

Even though the zIndex of polygon data layer is more it should show in front but point layer is showing in the front. In the API documentation its given that *points are always shown on front*. But if that's the case how to manage *data layers sequencing on map*?

Comment: Your question is similar to the following feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821988